# Find which other python types can an object be converted to?

Tags: python

As a simple example, assume a utility method, which accepts a python object `input_obj`, and `out_type`,a python `type` to convert (typecast) the object into

```
def convert_obj(input_obj,out_type):
```

-Examples

```
convert_obj('2','int')
#returns 2
convert_obj([1,2,3],'tuple')
#returns (1,2,3)
```

The method only supports objects of specific types like str,list,tuple, and then checks if that can be converted to the out_type specified.
This is the rulebook present in the method:

```
 supported_conversions = {
       tuple: [str, list, set],
       str: [tuple, float, list, long, int, set],
       float: [str, long, int],
       list: [tuple, str, set],
       long: [str, float, int],
       dict: [tuple, str, list, set],
       int: [str, float, long],
       set: [tuple, str, list],

    }
```

The keys in the `supported_conversions` are the allowed types for input_obj.

**Question** : Apart from using try/except over a list of all possible python types to convert a sample object of each type, and then seeing what are valid,
e.g. checking `str` conversion against [list,dict,tuple,int,tuple,set] 
is there a better way in python to generate the dict `supported_conversions`, given its keys ?

Note : Other exception on type conversion are to be ignored. e.g
"1" can be converted to integer 1,but "XYZ" cannot be. But this still
means str->int is a valid possible conversion.

Comment: *“is there a better way in python to generate the dict supported_conversions, given its keys?”* – That absolutely depends on how that function works! We don’t know what logic is behind it that could allow one converstion or the other.

Comment: @poke Primarily type conversion of a python object to another type, when it is known that by virtue of its data it will convert correctly, but the query is to know WHICH possible types can it be converted to.

Comment: But *how* does the type conversion work? I can easily think of a way to convert really *any* type into *anything*. It’s the type conversion algorithm (i.e. your `convert_obj` function) that solely decides on what kind of conversions it supports.

Comment: I'm confused by your criteria. You say `str -> int` is valid since some strings can be converted. But that doesn't mean `str` as a type can be converted to `int`, just that some strings can be read as integer values. Is there a practical application for this or is it just something you're trying to work out?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan  Example of practical application , just one specific example, I have a nested dictionary, which has few sets inside it. I cannot save it in mongodb using pymongo driver, as sets are not allowed in mongodb document. I would do a nested conversion of sets to lists to make it mongodb document friendly.
Hope this is a good example use case ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak But surely in that case you need to specifically format the set as a list? `str(list)` is a perfectly valid type conversion, but not what you'd need so I don't see what it allows you to know that it's a possibility.

Comment: If you can reliably determine with `try` - `except` whether a conversion is valid, you can update the dictionary the first time that conversion is attempted. Why do you need to pregenerate it for all possible type pairs?

Comment: @Vlad  I am asking for possibilities in python i.e. some inbuilt method, or properties of a type which can give this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem space is not well-defined enough for such a method to exist.
Some conversions will be destructive, and some could take place in more than one way. A few examples:

```
>>> list(set([1,2,2,3]))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list("hello")
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> ["hello"]
['hello']
>>> list({'a':1, 'b': 2})
['a', 'b']
>>> list({'a':1, 'b': 2}.iteritems())
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

For the sake of the argument, you can also convert a string to basically any Python type, by using `eval()`.

So, basically, it all depends on your use case.

If you really want to do a more exhaustive search, you can use the `types` module to get a list of built-in types, and then try to cross-convert (assuming you can get instances of each of these):

```
>>> import types
>>> [types.__dict__.get(t) for t in dir(types) if t.endswith('Type')]
[<type 'bool'>, <type 'buffer'>, <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>, <type 'classobj'>, <type 'code'>, <type 'complex'>, <type 'dictproxy'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'dict'>, <type 'ellipsis'>, <type 'file'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'frame'>, <type 'function'>, <type 'generator'>, <type 'getset_descriptor'>, <type 'instance'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'function'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'long'>, <type 'member_descriptor'>, <type 'instancemethod'>, <type 'module'>, <type 'NoneType'>, <type 'NotImplementedType'>, <type 'object'>, <type 'slice'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'traceback'>, <type 'tuple'>, <type 'type'>, <type 'instancemethod'>, <type 'unicode'>, <type 'xrange'>]
```

I don't know if you need to generate your `supported_conversions` dictionary beforehand, though. Assuming you always convert `intype` to `outtype` by `outtype(intype_value)`, you can attempt that and then update a dictionary that maps `(intype, outtype) -> bool`, and so it won't attempt the conversion again if it failed the first time.